# Submit form with only two clicks on Submit Django

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-views, django-forms

I created a page with questions to the phone, I need that when,  when a person clicks on the submit form, he must submit the form with one click, and change the same form with one click too.

But for now, it can be done with just two mouse clicks.

my models.py:

```
class Items_buy(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'items_buy'
        verbose_name = 'Телефон который покупаем'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Телефоны которые покупаем'

    image_phone = ResizedImageField(size=[100,100], upload_to='for_sell/',verbose_name='Фотография модели телефона')
    model_produkt = models.TextField(max_length=80, verbose_name='Модель продукта ')
    text = models.TextField(max_length=500, verbose_name='Текст')
    max_prise = models.FloatField(verbose_name='Максимальная цена telefoha')
    image_phone_for_buy_bord = ResizedImageField(size=[100,100],upload_to='for_sell/',verbose_name='Фотография модели телефона ha prodazy')


    def __str__(self):
        return self.model_produkt

class Question(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'question'
        verbose_name = 'Вопрос к телефону'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Вопросы к телефону'

 
    items_buy = models.ForeignKey(Items_buy, on_delete=models.RESTRICT)
    titles= models.CharField(max_length=150,verbose_name='Заголовок вопросa')
    question_text =models.TextField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Заголовок вопросa text')
    #max_prise_qustion = models.FloatField(verbose_name='Максимальная цена')

   
    def __str__(self):
           return self.titles


class Choice(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'choice'
        verbose_name = 'Выбор ответа'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Выбор ответов'
    
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.RESTRICT,related_name="options")
    title = models.CharField(max_length=1000, verbose_name='Заголовок выбора')
    price_question = models.FloatField(verbose_name='Цена ответа')
    #lock_other = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Смотреть другой вариант ответа')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.price_question)

class Answer(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'answer'
        verbose_name = 'Ответ на вопрос'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Ответы на вопросы'

    items_buy = models.ForeignKey(Items_buy, on_delete=models.RESTRICT)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.RESTRICT)
    choice = models.ForeignKey(Choice, on_delete=models.RESTRICT)
    #created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.items_buy)
```

my forms.py:

```
class AnswersForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, instance: Items_buy, **kwargs):
        self.instance = instance
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        questions = Question.objects.filter(items_buy_id=instance)
        existing_answers = {
            question_id: choice_id
            for question_id, choice_id in Answer.objects.filter(
                items_buy=self.instance
            ).values_list("question_id", "choice_id")
        }
        for question in questions:
            self.fields["question_%s" % question.id] = forms.ChoiceField(
                help_text=mark_safe(question.titles),
                label=mark_safe(question.question_text),
                choices=question.options.all().values_list("id", "title"),
                widget=forms.RadioSelect(attrs={"class": "form-check-input"}),
            )
            self.fields["question_%s" % question.id].initial = {} #existing_answers.get(
                #question.id, None
            #) 

    def save(self):
        answers_to_create = []
        for field, value in self.cleaned_data.items():
            if field.startswith("question_"):
                question_id = field.split("_")[-1]
                answers_to_create.append(
                    Answer(
                        items_buy=self.instance,
                        question_id=question_id,
                        choice_id=value,
                    )
                )
        Answer.objects.filter(items_buy=self.instance).delete()
        Answer.objects.bulk_create(answers_to_create)
```

my views.py:

```
def getqestionses(request, pk):
    iphone = get_object_or_404(Items_buy, pk = pk)
    total_score = iphone.answer_set.all().aggregate(total_score=Sum("choice__price_question"))["total_score"]
    form = AnswersForm(request.POST or None, instance=iphone)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save() 
    return render(request, "getqestionses.html", {'form': form, 'total_score':total_score, 'iphone':iphone})
```

my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
{% load widget_tweaks %}
{% block content %}
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/qestionses.css' %}" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
  {% include 'navbar.html' %}
  <div class="div">
     <h1>{{ iphones.model_produkt }}</h1>  
    <form method="post">
        <div class="ded">
          {% csrf_token %}
          {% for field in form %}
          <div class="qestion">
            {{ field.label_tag}}
          </div>
          <div class="help_text">
          {{ field.help_text }}
          </div>
          <div class="form-check">
            {% for radio in field %}
            {{ radio.tag }}
            <div class="chack-button">
            {{ radio.choice_label }}
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
      {% endfor %}
      <button type="submit" class="button">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>  
    <div class="next-block">
      <h1> {{ total_score }} </h1>
      <form action="{% url 'orderforsel' iphone.id %}"> 
        <button class="button-next-block">next page for order create</button>
      </form>
      </div>
  </div>  
  <script>
    const submitButton = document.querySelector('.button');
    const nextBlock = document.querySelector('.next-block');
    
    nextBlock.style.display = 'none'; // hide the next-block div initially
    
    submitButton.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
      event.preventDefault(); // prevent the form from submitting
      
      // Simulate a double click by waiting for a short delay before displaying the next-block div
      setTimeout(() => {
        nextBlock.style.display = 'block';
        submitButton.style.display = 'none';
      }, 200);
    });
  </script>
</body>
{% include 'info.html' %}
{% include 'end_navbar.html' %}
{% endblock %}
```

I tried adding a script to get 2 clicks in one click but unfortunately that didn't change my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not have to be this complicated. Javascript has a `dblclick` event.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/dblclick_event

This will allow you to easily capture doubleclicks